# Como analizo un dato introducido desde la consola para saber si es un float o no?

Tags: java

[image: Es un programa sencillo pero al compilar no consigo que funcione correctamente]

¿Como completo el código para analizar si el valor introducido por la consola es un float o no?

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. El código y los mensajes de error van _como texto, con formato_: [aquí está el porqué](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask]. Además, ¿leíste el error que te está dando el compilador?

Comment: No pongas fotos del código; nadie lo va a mirar o trabajar con él. Pon el código y errores como texto.

Comment: Hola Fernando en este hilo  de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727569/how-to-check-whether-input-value-is-integer-or-float) tienes la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacer uso de Try catch con metodo Boolean,pasandole el dato en este ejemplo de tipo String y verificar si es un float o no

```
public static boolean isValidFloat(String s) {
    boolean isValid = true;

    try {
        Float.parseFloat(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```